# SQL - Choose which duplicate value to select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a datetime, value and user.
This table has multiple rows for the same datetime but with a different user and value.

I want select distinct datetime with the corresponding value and user. 
Where there is a duplicate datetime with different users, the value that user2 has input should be prioritised.

```
Table 1
-----------------
DateTime|    Value|    User
--------|---------|---------
1/1/17  |       10|    User1
2/1/17  |       30|    User1
3/1/17  |       10|    User1
1/1/17  |       90|    User2
2/1/17  |       80|    User2
```

So from the above, I would end up with

```
1/1/17   |     90| User2
2/1/17   |     80| User2
3/1/17   |     10| User1
```

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this but I can't for the life of me work out how to do it!

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How did u gt 80 for date 2/1/17 ?

Comment: sorry typo, meant to be 90. Will update.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite simple! Using window functions and common table expressions

```
; with x as (
select [DateTime], value, [User], row_num = row_number() over(partition by [DateTime] order by [User] desc) from Table1 
)
select x.* from x where row_num = 1
```

Comment: This takes advantage of the fact that 'User2' > 'User1', in a more general setting the order by clause would have been different.

Answer (score 2):

This will always prioritize the input from `'User2'`, even when there is input from `'User1'` and `'User3'`.

```
;with cte as (
  select *
  , rn = row_number() over (
      partition by [DateTime]
      order by (case when [user] = 'User2' then 0 else 1 end) asc
      )
  from t
)
select * 
from cte 
where rn=1
```

rextester http://rextester.com/AZVA85684

results:

```
+----------+-------+-------+----+
| DateTime | value | user  | rn |
+----------+-------+-------+----+
| 1/1/17   |    90 | User2 |  1 |
| 2/1/17   |    80 | User2 |  1 |
| 3/1/17   |    10 | User1 |  1 |
+----------+-------+-------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T as table
(
    [DateTime] nvarchar(100),
    VALUE INT,
    [USER] VARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES
('1/1/17', 10, 'User1'),
('2/1/17', 30, 'User1'),
('3/1/17', 10, 'User1'),
('1/1/17', 90, 'User2'),
('2/1/17', 80, 'User2')

SELECT t.[DateTime], t.VALUE, t.[USER]
FROM @T t
    JOIN (
        SELECT [DateTime], MAX([USER]) AS [USER] 
        FROM @T 
        GROUP BY [DateTime]
    ) u ON u.[DateTime] = t.[DateTime] AND u.[USER] = t.[USER]
ORDER BY VALUE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte
as
(
select 
*,
row_number() over (partition by date order by replace(user,'user','') desc) as rownum
from
#temp
)
select * from cte where rownum=1
```